# Nodejs in sandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, sandbox

I'm using nodejs as a middle-man between a client browser and the server to handle all the requests. I'm trying to use nodejs as a filter tool and highlight (if not) all malicious scripts. But I realize that nodejs let the script to run with the current environment privilege. So, I decide to run it in a new context by installing sandbox (`npm install sandbox` or `git clone git://github.com/gf3/sandbox.git`). 
However when I run node I have this following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method
>   \'runInNewContext\' of undefined'

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the inbuild sandbox abilities of [node 0.4.6](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/all.html#executing_JavaScript).

```
var localVar = 123,
    usingscript, evaled,
    vm = require('vm');

usingscript = vm.runInThisContext('localVar = 1;',
  'myfile.vm');
console.log('localVar: ' + localVar + ', usingscript: ' +
  usingscript);
evaled = eval('localVar = 1;');
console.log('localVar: ' + localVar + ', evaled: ' +
  evaled);

// localVar: 123, usingscript: 1
// localVar: 1, evaled: 1
```

Comment: No I haven't, I did not know about that. Thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: runInThisContext() is not secure - see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1469

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but apparently there's an `npm` module for this: [`sandbox`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandbox):

> A nifty javascript sandbox for node.js
>
> Some features
>
> - Can be used to execute untrusted code.
> - Support for timeouts (e.g. prevent infinite loops)
> - Support for memory errors (and memory errors)
> - Handles errors gracefully
> - Restricted code (cannot access node.js methods)
> - Supports console.log and print utility methods
> - Supports interprocess messaging with the sandboxed code

This is [referenced](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1469#issuecomment-3681701) by the [bug report](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1469) on `runThisInContext` flagging up that it is not secure [mentioned by broofa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748985/nodejs-in-sandbox#comment9005491_5749017) in a comment on another answer saying to use `runThisInContext`.