# Implementing extends/super manually

Tags: javascript, prototype-pattern

I'm building classes dynamically based on descriptive data pulled from a database. For instance, if the data reads as this:

```
ClassName = ExampleParent
Method1.name = "greet"
Method1.code = "console.log(\"Parent hello\");"
```

and building it like this works just fine:

```
classList[ClassName] = function(){}
classList[ClassName].prototype[Method1.name] = Function(Method1.code);

var Bob = new classList["ExampleParent"]();
Bob.greet();
```

But I'm stumped on how to dynamically create inheritance:

```
ClassName = ExampleChild
ClassExtends = ExampleParent
Method1.name = "greet"
Method1.code = "super.greet(); console.log(\"Child hello\");"
```

I don't see how I could use **ExampleChild.prototype** to point to both ExampleParent AND contain ExampleChild's custom methods, and even when I tried, it said that *super* was unknown. I don't need to support anything fancy (private, static, etc)... I just need *this* and *super* to work. Hints?

Comment: Can you show your JavaScript code currently being generated? Also, `super` is only available from ES6 and within functions declared inside the `class ClassName extends Object` syntax.

Comment: Apologies, I see the JavaScript code from the 1st example now, point still stands about super though.

Comment: @HeinrichHenning: Oddly, you can use `super` in an object initializer, too, not that it helps here (much). [Example, just for fun.](https://jsfiddle.net/cmw3L31v/)

Comment: That is very interesting! Just read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super where they explain how it works. Just a note, both the `super` and the `setPrototypeOf` is ECMAScript 6 standards, which is quite widely implemented already in especially chrome and firefox, and bit less, but not to badly in Edge

Comment: I'm in Node, strict mode, using ES6 classes in the structural part of the server code. This part in question here is constructing the "user supplied", dynamically coded objects during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't without using `eval` (or effectively using `eval` by having `Function` return a function that does the work), but that's still in line with what you're doing as `Function` allows arbitrary code execution just like `eval` does. Still, it's ugly.

**It's important that you absolutely trust the source of the data.** Because `eval` (and `Function`) allow executing arbitrary code, you must not (for instance) allow User A to write the code that will be stored in the database for User B to retrieve and use without **absolutely trusting** User A. It puts User B at risk, potentially exposing them to malicious code from User A.

With that caveat in place, you can do it with `eval`, e.g.:

```
const className = "ExampleChild";
const parentName = "ExampleParent";
const methodName = "greet";
const methodCode = "super.greet();";
const C = eval(`
    class ${className} extends ${parentName} {
        ${methodName}() {
            ${methodCode}
        }
    }`
);
```

You may need an object to store the classes on by their runtime names, since that's what you'll need for the `extends` clause.

Example:

```js
const classes = {};
function buildClass(spec) {
    const extendsClause = spec.parentName ? ` extends classes.${spec.parentName}` : "";
    const methods = spec.methods.map(
        mspec =>  `${mspec.name}() { ${mspec.code} }`
    ).join("\n");
    const cls = classes[spec.className] = eval(`
        class ${spec.className} ${extendsClause} {
            ${methods}
        }`
    );
    return cls;
}

const specs = [
    {
        className: "ExampleParent",
        methods: [
          {name: "greet", code: "console.log(\"Parent hello\");"}
        ]
    },
    {
        className: "ExampleChild",
        parentName: "ExampleParent",
        methods: [
            {name: "greet", code: "super.greet(); console.log(\"Child hello\");"}
        ]
    }
];

specs.forEach(buildClass);

let c = new classes.ExampleChild();
c.greet();
```

Comment: @Bergi: Yikes, why was my hindbrain saying `""`? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, seems pretty straight forward, will give this a shot. Any advice on how to sandbox this in Node? Right now all the "untrusted" code will be written by me, but I'd like to open it to others in the long run if I could know it was safe to do so.

Comment: @JeramieH not easily possible (and a very broad topic). You better only run code of people whom you trust.

Comment: @JeramieH: I'd be ***very*** cautious. There are a couple of answers on that topic here: [*Nodejs in sandbox*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748985/nodejs-in-sandbox)

Comment: Marked this one as Answer because this is essentially the route that ended up working for me, basically building the source text and running it through Node's vm (sandbox) module. It's working for me now, and that's all I need. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You may create a property called `super`inside the subclass prototype, and set it with the instance of the superclass.

Take a look at this example:

```js
// -- Base Structure - This code is fixed, hard coded --
var classList = {};

// Register a new class
function registerClass(definition) {
  var cls, i, method;

  cls = function() {};

  if (definition.superClass) {
    cls.prototype.super = new classList[definition.superClass]();
  }

  classList[definition.name] = cls;
  cls.constructor = cls;

  for (i = 0; i < definition.methods.length; i++) {
    method = definition.methods[i];
    cls.prototype[method.name] = Function(method.code);
  }
}


// -- Here you need to get data from your database --

// Super Class
registerClass({
  name: "SuperClass",
  methods: [{
    name: "greet",
    code: "console.log(\"Super hello\");"
  }]
});


// Sub Class
registerClass({
  name: "SubClass",
  superClass: "SuperClass",
  methods: [{
    name: "greet",
    code: "this.super.greet(); console.log(\"Sub hello\");"
  }]
});


// Usage
var obj = new classList.SubClass();
obj.greet();
```